# Summarizing a variable in Stata and extracting standard deviation

Tags: stata

I am trying to create a variable for each year in my data based on mathematical expressions of other variables (I have annual data and used "..." to avoid writing each year). I am using the summarize command in Stata to extract the standard deviation but Stata does not recognize the `frac` variable. I have tried to use `egen` but that results in an unknown function error. Using `gen` results in an already defined variable. I would appreciate anyone helping with the following code or pointing me to a link where this issue has been discussed.

```
    foreach yr of numlist 1995...2012 {
            local row = `yr' - 1994
            local numerator = 100*(income - L1.income)
            local denominator = ((abs(income) + abs(L1.income)) / 2)
            local frac = (`numerator' / `denominator') 
            summarize frac
            local sdfrac = r(sd)
            matrix C[`row', 1] = `numerator'
            matrix C[`row', 2] = `denominator'
            matrix C[`row', 3] = `sdfrac'
        }
```

Comment: `summarize` is to be applied to some variable (or none at all). You apply it to a local that takes on a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question right, maybe you don't need to use a loop until the end and then you can post the results to a postfile:

This is just a thought:

```
tempname memhold
tempfile filename

postfile `memhold' year sdfrac using `filename'

gen row=year-1994
gen numerator=100*(income-L1.income)
gen denominator=((abs(income)+abs(L1.income))/2)
gen frac=numerator/denominator

foreach yr of numlist 1995...2012 {

summarize frac if year=`yr'
local sdfrac=r(sd)
post `memhold' (year) (`sdfrac')

}

postclose `memhold'
clear all 
use `filename'

*View Results
list
```

This code should get you a data set with the name of the year and the standard deviation of the frac variable as variables.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This looks intuitive to me but when the program got to the loop, it resulted in an invalid syntax error. It is unclear to me what the problem is. 

You are correct in that I am trying to generate a result that shows the year (or some row value that counts each year) and the standard deviation of the frac variable. In my original code I wanted to see the components as well (numerator and denominator) to make sure the code was generating my hand-written results.

Comment: Need == not = in the summarize statement.

Comment: @Nick Cox 

Thanks for pointing that out. It fixed the issue and generated the results :)

Comment: Sorry about that. If I had data I could've fixed the error.  Yes it should be year==`yr'.

Comment: @Nick Cox
@Pcarlitz

Do you have any suggestions on how to generate results by subgroups, specifically by race and sex for every year? I modified the code you recommended (below) but I receive syntax error but do not know where/why the error comes up. 

    postfile `memhold' year sdfrac sex race using myresults
    levels of sex, local (s)
    levelsof race, local (r)
    foreach a of local s {
    foreach b of local r {
    forval yr = 1995/2012 {
    summarize frac if year==`yr'& sex ==`a' & race==`b'
    post `memhold' (`yr') (`r(sd)') (`sex') (`race')
    }
    }
    }

Comment: New question please! I decline to read so much code in such a form.

Comment: Agree with @NickCox. I would think it would involve adding in the following code: `sort race` `by race: summarize frac if year==`yr'`

Answer (score 0):

This code modifies that by @Pcarlitz, mostly by simplifying it. I can't check with your data, which I don't have.

It's too long to fit into a comment.

I would not use a temporary file as you want to save these results, it seems.

```
tempname memhold
postfile `memhold' year sdfrac using myresults

gen frac = (100*(income - L1.income))/((abs(income) + abs(L1.income))/2)

forval yr = 1995/2012 {
    summarize frac if year==`yr'
    post `memhold' (`yr') (`r(sd)')
}

postclose `memhold'

use myresults 
list
```

UPDATE As in a later answer, consider `collapse` as a much simpler direct alternative here.

Comment: Thanks again for your assistance and patience. Yes I do want to save these results and your code helps.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, OP added a question about code similar to this (but ignored the request to post it in a more civilised form). Note that backticks or left quotation marks in Stata clash with SO mark-up codes in comments. Presumably some

```
tempname memhold
```

definition preceded this.

```
postfile `memhold' year sdfrac sex race using myresults     
levels of sex, local (s)     
levelsof race, local (r)     
foreach a of local s {     
    foreach b of local r {     
        forval yr = 1995/2012 {     
           summarize frac if year == `yr' & sex == `a' & race == `b' 
           post `memhold' (`yr') (`r(sd)') (`sex') (`race') 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Let's focus on what the problem is. You want the standard deviations of `frac` for all combinations of `sex`, `race` and `year` in a separate file. That's one line

```
collapse (sd) frac, by(year sex race)
```

If you want to see a table alongside the data, consider

```
egen group = group(sex race year), label
```

and then

```
tab group, su(frac)
```

or

```
tabstat frac, by(group) stat(sd)
```